# Python getrusage with RUSAGE_CHILDREN behaves stangely?

Tags: python, getrusage

Recently I have made a plan to develop a Online Judge system (like [spoj](http://spoj.com)). And I have write a judge script in python. It forks every time when it receives one submitted code, and then compile the code and use `subprocess.Popen` to start the program. But when I get program's memory usage with `resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN)`, it returns memory of the forked python process instead of the subprocess.

Below is some of my code:

```
try:
    programThread = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn = self.limit, bufsize = -1)
except OSError:
    self.status.value = -2
    return -2
self.JudgeID.value = programThread.pid
programOutput = programThread.communicate(_in)
self.status.value = 0
Res = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN)
self.cpuusage.value = Res.ru_utime + Res.ru_stime
self.memoryusage.value = Res.ru_maxrss * resource.getpagesize()
```

`cpuusage` and `memoryusage` is shared memory created by `multiprocessing.Value`, the value of `memoryusage` is 12M. But via `top`, i've found, that the memory usage of forked python process is 12M while the subprocess is 900K. Are there anything wrong with my code? Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called `maxrss` because it's the maximum of the RSS usage of the child.  The problem is that `subprocess` uses the standard way to create the subprocess: it first forks, creating a new process id (`childpid`), and then `execv` the intended subprocess' executable (which doesn't change the `childpid`).  Then `resource` returns the maximum of the RSS among the lifetime of this `childpid`.  If this child ran both a forked copy of Python at 12MB and another program at 900K, then the result is 12MB.

I don't really see how to fix this problem...

Comment: You may need to execute from Python a small wrapper program written in C, which itself executes the real process, waits for it, and finally gets the RUSAGE_CHILDREN.  This way, the reported value will be the maximum of the size taken by this small wrapper program and the real program, rather than the maximum of the size taken by Python and the real program.